# Android Google Play Services for turn based game , Not able to receive invitation with default UI

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am new to turn based game development and trying to develop a turn based game. I am using default UI for selecting players

```
Intent intent = Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(getApiClient(), 1, 1, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
```

When I select player sand say Play, other player is supposed to get notification. But that player is not receiving invitation / notification.

```
@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {

    updateLayouts();   

    Games.Invitations.registerInvitationListener(getApiClient(), this);
            // developer document says that above line is not required
            // include or exclude for me it is not making any difference

}

@Override
public void onInvitationReceived(Invitation invitation) {
    Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "An invitation has arrived from "
                    + invitation.getInviter().getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

    Log.d(TAG, "Invitation arrived from " + invitation.getInviter().getDisplayName());



}
```

Here is my onActivtityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);

    if (request == RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES) {
        // Returning from the 'Select Match' dialog

        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
            return;
        }

        TurnBasedMatch match = data
                .getParcelableExtra(com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);

        if (match != null) {
            updateMatch(match);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Match = " + match);
    } 
    else if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
            return;
        }

        // get the invitee list
        final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

        Log.d(TAG, "Invitees count = " + invitees.size());
        for(int i=0; i<invitees.size(); i++){
            Log.d(TAG, invitees.get(i));
        }

        // get auto-match criteria
        Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
        int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(
                Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        int maxAutoMatchPlayers
        = data.getIntExtra(
                Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
        if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
            autoMatchCriteria
            = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                    minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);

            Log.d(TAG, "minAutoMatchPlayers > 0");

        } else {
            autoMatchCriteria = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "minAutoMatchPlayers <= 0");
        }

        TurnBasedMatchConfig tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
                .addInvitedPlayers(invitees)                    
                .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria).build();


        // kick the match off
        Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer
        .createMatch(getApiClient(), tbmc)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
                processResult(result);
            }
        });

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        showSpinner();
    }
}
```

Can Anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The notification happens after the first player (who created the match) takes his turn by calling Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn() and not right away after the match is created.

Answer (score 0):

Can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986344/1032167). If there is no invitations (even when your app is closed), the account-lvl restrictions can block them.