# Possible reasons for android device failing to receive google play games notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-play-games

Regarding to [TBMP Skeleton: Why are both onTurnBasedMatchReceived and onInvitationReceived not called on my physical device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186278/tbmp-skeleton-why-are-both-onturnbasedmatchreceived-and-oninvitationreceived-no)

Initially I thought that the problem was something with my code, even thoough it made no sense, since it worked on my emulator just fine + its very similar to the one in tbmp skeleton sample.

Now I definitely think the problem is with my device, so id like to know what could be blocking notifications from Google Play Games.

In my emulator I get a ton of notifications from Google Play Games in the notification bar, but nothing in the physical device.
The device is Xperia L 4.2.2.

EDIT:
Yes, google play services notifications checkbox is checked.
Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="@string/app_id" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
            <activity
                android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.MYACTIVITY"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I've tried and searched everywhere for this, maybe someone else went through the same.

Comment: are you received google push notification?

Comment: I think the problem is i dont receive any kind of notifications from google. If i understand this correctly, im not explicity using push notifications, but google play services uses an identical method for sending notifications, so my answer would be no, i dont receive push notifications :P

Comment: Ok, i somehow just fixed it.. i was around Gmail app, and i checked something about automatic synchronizing or something like that.. Weird that i have to do this but now im receiving notifications :)

Answer (score 2):

This 'bug' caused me A LOT of trouble when testing an app I'm developing.

It has something to do with what 'skm' said in his last comment, but not specifically about Gmail not being synced. In my case trying to sync Gmail didn't really "enable" syncing it just synced it once and kept being un-synced. So what I had to do was go into: `Settings->Data Usage->[Three dots button]->Auto-sync data.` Doing this enables syncing so you can actually sync stuff again, sync it all and then you can uncheck whatever you don't want to sync. And after this, notifications from Google Play Services will once again be able to get received.

Hope it helps anyone else!

Comment: Can't find Sync at Data usage any more.. Has it been shifted to Settings>>>Accounts>>>Google, possibly??

Comment: On Android P, it's as you say, Settings > Accounts > [Click your Google Account] >  Account sync > [Three dots] > Sync now. But this issue is probably already solved if you're on this new version on Android(/and Google Play Services).

Answer (score 0):

On your device go to:

```
 Settings ---> Apps ---> Google Play Services
```

Then check to see if the notifications CheckBox is set.

Answer (score 0):

Select

```
   Settings > Apps > Google Play Services
```

then tick the checkbox for notifications

If that still doesn't work, please post the `meta-data` fields of your manifest file (while obfuscating the key).

Comment: Yes the notification checkbox is checked, here is my meta-data manifest:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but before I resync'd everything like @Whyser said... I first cleared the cache from Google Play Services & Google Play Games. Then when I went back to the settings in Google Play Games, I saw Multiplayer toggle got reset! I restarted the phone, and notifications started.