# OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener does not trigger

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to get the OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener to trigger but it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code example that I am using. I get a valid GoogleApiClient and am already signed in (I have other Listeners going in other parts of code).

The goal is to have a single class that can handle this event, by passing the GoogleApiClient through and have it callback here (I have no other way of getting code to trigger such as the BaseGameActivity because the code is within another LIB and I am writing additional code).

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

```
package com.google.example.games.pluginsupport;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMatch;

public class TurnBaseMatchHelper implements OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener {

    public interface TurnBasedMatchListener {
        void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match);
        void onTurnBasedMatchRemoved(String matchId);
    }

    private static TurnBaseMatchHelper turnbaseInterface = null;
    private TurnBasedMatchListener sTurnBasedMatchListener = null;

    public static void registerTurnBasedCallbacks(GoogleApiClient _googleApiClient, TurnBasedMatchListener sListener) {

        if (turnbaseInterface == null) {
            turnbaseInterface = new TurnBaseMatchHelper();
        }       
        turnbaseInterface.sTurnBasedMatchListener = sListener;

        Log.d("Unity", "registerTurnBasedCallbacks");

        Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(_googleApiClient, turnbaseInterface);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match) {

        Log.d("Unity", "onTurnBasedMatchReceived");

        if (turnbaseInterface.sTurnBasedMatchListener != null) {
             sTurnBasedMatchListener.onTurnBasedMatchReceived(match);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTurnBasedMatchRemoved(String matchId) {

        Log.d("Unity", "onTurnBasedMatchRemoved");

        if (turnbaseInterface.sTurnBasedMatchListener != null) {
             sTurnBasedMatchListener.onTurnBasedMatchRemoved(matchId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my similar problem answer.

[From post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986344/1032167)
Go to the Settings -> Account and sync-> turn on Auto-sync checkbox

Comment: Thanks for spreading this on multiple questions, that setting was indeed the cause in my case!